# What's the difference between keras.datasets.mnist and tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, mnist, dcgan

I am analysing [this DCGAN](https://github.com/roatienza/Deep-Learning-Experiments/blob/master/Experiments/Tensorflow/GAN/dcgan_mnist.py). When I use `input_data` from `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist`, as seen in [line 144](https://github.com/roatienza/Deep-Learning-Experiments/blob/master/Experiments/Tensorflow/GAN/dcgan_mnist.py#L144):

```
self.x_train = input_data.read_data_sets("mnist",\
        one_hot=True).train.images
```

I obtain reasonably good results:
[image]
Though when I use `mnist` from `keras.datasets` and the 144th line looks like this:

```
(xtr, ytr), (xte, yte) = mnist.load_data();
    self.x_train = xtr
```

I get horribly bad results:
[image]
I have checked manually a few images from both datasets and they are quite similar.

So what is the difference between `keras.datasets.mnist` and `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist`? Why are the resulting images so different? What am I doing wrong with `keras.datasets.mnist`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that the images in `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist` have been normalized to the range [0, 1] and therefore you obtain better results. Whereas, the values in MNIST dataset in Keras are in the range [0, 255] and you are expected to normalize them (if needed, of course). Try this:

```py
(xtr, ytr), (xte, yte) = mnist.load_data()
xtr = xtr.astype('float32') / 255.0
xte = xte.astype('float32') / 255.0
```